# Running Python Script From Informatica Cloud

Tags: python, shell, cloud, informatica

I am trying to run a Python script that runs a bunch of queries against my tables on my Snowflake database and based on the results of the queries stores the output in Snowflake tables. This new company that I work for leverage Informatica Cloud as their ETL tool and while my tool works on Microsoft Azure (ADF) and Azure Batch, I cannot figure out for the life of me, how to trigger the Python script from Informatica Cloud Data Integration tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be tricky for cloud implementation.

1. You can create an executable from your py script. Then put that file in Informatica cloud agent server. Then you can call it using shell command.
2. You can also put the py file in agent server and run it using shell like
   $PYTHON_HOME/python your_script.py
   You need to make sure py version is compatible and you have all packages installed in agent server.

You can refer to the below screenshot for how to setup shell command. Then you can run it as part of some workflow. Schedule it if needed.

[image: Properties Screenshot]